# Display Vaadin 14 button as a link

Tags: vaadin, vaadin14

Can a Button be displayed as a link in Vaadin 14?

That is, can it be displayed inline with the label underlined on hover?

In Vaadin 8 [the equivalent](https://vaadin.com/api/framework/8.14.1/com/vaadin/ui/themes/ValoTheme.html#BUTTON_LINK) looks to be:

```
button.setStyleName(VaaloTheme.BUTTON_LINK);
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your use case is internal linking to the other views / routes of the application, I would recommend to use `RouterLink` component instead of a button. For linking external links I would recommend `Anchor` component. These will be semantically a better match.

However the `Button` can be styled as well. There is no exactly similar built in variant for button, but one comes close, `ButtonVariant.TERTIARY_INLINE`.

So if you do `button.addThemeVariants(ButtonVariant.TERTIARY_INLINE)` you will get a button that is only a text, but the text is not underlined.

If you really need to have the text underlined, you need to import additional style module (this builds on top of the `ButtonVariant.TERTIARY_INLINE` variant. Place this in "frontend/styles/my-button.css"

```
:host(.underline) [part~="label"] {
    text-decoration: underline;
    font-weight: 400;
}
```

And import it using `@CssImport("./styles/my-button.css", themeFor="vaadin-button")` and add the class name `button.addClassName("underline")`

Comment: Great. The underlining on hover can be achieved with:
:host(:hover) [part~="label"] {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

Answer (score 3):

With flow you can go the other way around: how can I make a link work
like a button.

E.g. you can add a `click` listener on the element of an `Anchor`:

```
new Anchor().tap{
    setText("Greet")
    getElement().tap {
        getStyle().set('cursor', 'pointer')
        addEventListener('click', {
            println "Clicked"
        })
    }
}
```