# Display LitRenderer grid cell button as a link in Vaadin 24

Tags: vaadin, vaadin-flow, vaadin-grid

I have a button inside a grid cell defined as follows:

```java
private static Renderer<LogRecord> createStatusRenderer(Grid<LogRecord> grid) {
    return LitRenderer
            .<LogRecord> of("<vaadin-button theme=\"${item.style}\" @click=\"${handleClick}\">${item.status}</vaadin-button>")
            .withProperty("style", r -> r.isFailed() ? "error" : "success")
            .withProperty("status", ComponentLogRecord::getStatus)
            .withFunction("handleClick", r -> {
                 if (r.hasMessage()) grid.setDetailsVisible(r, !grid.isDetailsVisible(r));
            });
}
```

Could you please advice how to modify that code in order to achieve the following:

1. Display error button as a link (of red color).
2. Display OK button as a simple text of green color.
3. (alternative to 1) Display error button as simple text of red color with arrow down suffix.

My goal is to display a button as a simple grid cell text but advice user to click on error buttons to show error details.

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69695794/7126496) approach, but without success.
"tertiary-inline" theme works but it's not quite clear how to specify additional style class in template. Also "text-decoration: underline;" doesn't work even if I specify it directly in browser developer console ...

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you tried using the strings from `ButtonVariant` separated with spaces for the `theme` attribute?

Comment: Thank you for advice! Just tried and it works. So it's more or less clear now how to display colored button but it's still a question how to display underlined text. Also I noticed that button font weight is a bit "bolder" than grid cell one. So it would be nice to have an ability to style cell button additionally ...

Comment: I'd guess that regular styling rules (e.g. `components/vaadin-button.css` or the new v24 way should apply.  So also add `class` and provide the CSS by one of those two measn?

Comment: `class` attribute doesn't work, probably template doesn't support it. I added class to the `styles.css`, it should be visible.

Comment: Very likely only for V24 with the new rules. What version are you on and what exactly have you tired. Please edit your question and add your new insights.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the sollution I finally implemented. I was not able to implement underline but implemented an icon. May be it is not the best one but working and probably would be useful for somebody.

```java
        return LitRenderer.<LogRecord> of("""
                    <vaadin-button theme="${item.theme}" style="font-weight: 400" @click="${handleClick}"> \
                        <vaadin-icon icon="${item.icon}" slot="suffix"></vaadin-icon> \
                        ${item.status} \
                    </vaadin-button>
                    """)
                .withProperty("theme", r -> r.isError() ? "tertiary-inline error" : "tertiary-inline success")
                .withProperty("status", LogRecord::getStatus)
                .withProperty("icon", r -> r.isError() ? "vaadin:angle-down" : "")
                .withFunction("handleClick", r -> {
                    if (r.hasMessage()) grid.setDetailsVisible(r, !grid.isDetailsVisible(r));
                });
```